# ROS two different nodes in the same package

Tags: ros, multiple, nodes

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
My package name is tum_ardrone. Inside the src file I have Autopilot,StateEstimation and UINode. I Created Autopilot2,StateEstimation2 and UINode2 to run two robots.

When I run the launch file:

```
<launch>
<group ns="controlo_drone1">
<node name="drone_stateestimation" pkg="tum_ardrone" type="drone_stateestimation">
</node>
<node name="drone_autopilot" pkg="tum_ardrone" type="drone_autopilot">
</node>
<node name="drone_gui" pkg="tum_ardrone" type="drone_gui">
</node>
</group>

<group ns="controlo_drone2">
<node name="drone_stateestimation2" pkg="tum_ardrone" type="drone_stateestimation">
</node>
<node name="drone_autopilot2" pkg="tum_ardrone" type="drone_autopilot">
</node>
<node name="drone_gui2" pkg="tum_ardrone" type="drone_gui">
</node>
</group>
</launch>
```

I want to run Autopilot,StateEstimation and UINode and Autopilot2,StateEstimation2 and UINode2.

But when I run the launch file it runs two instances of Autopilot,StateEstimation and UINode and not my Autopilot2,StateEstimation2 and UINode2.

Basically I copy-paste the folders inside src ( Autopilot,StateEstimation and UINode ) and changed the code in each one to read /drone1/image_raw and /drone2_image_raw in ( Autopilot2,StateEstimation2 and UINode2 ).

The problem is that when I run roslaunch it only starts 2 instances of the nodes Autopilot,StateEstimation and UINode and not Autopilot,StateEstimation and UINode and Autopilot2,StateEstimation2 and UINode2

Any idea? Please help me.

---

Edit: Maybe I have to mess with CMakeLists.txt? But what can I do?

```
    #
# Author: Jakob Engel <jajuengel@gmail.com>
# Contributor: Stefan Wilkes <stefan.wilkes@gmail.com>
#
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(tum_ardrone)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  ardrone_autonomy
  cv_bridge
  dynamic_reconfigure
  geometry_msgs
  sensor_msgs
  std_msgs
  std_srvs
  message_generation
  roscpp
  rospy
)

# Compile third party libs
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(thirdparty
    URL ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/thirdparty.tar.gz
    PREFIX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/thirdparty
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND make
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
)

# ------------------- add dynamic reconfigure api ------------------------------------
generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
  cfg/AutopilotParams.cfg
  cfg/GUIParams.cfg
  cfg/StateestimationParams.cfg
)

################################################
## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
################################################

## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
add_message_files(FILES filter_state.msg)

## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
add_service_files(
    DIRECTORY srv
    FILES
    SetReference.srv
    SetMaxControl.srv
    SetInitialReachDistance.srv
    SetStayWithinDistance.srv
    SetStayTime.srv
)

## Generate added messages 
generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime std_msgs ardrone_autonomy)

###########
## Build ##
###########
include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# --------------------------- stateestimation & PTAM --------------------------------
# set header ans source files
set(STATEESTIMATION_SOURCE_FILES       
    src/stateestimation/GLWindow2.cc
    src/stateestimation/GLWindowMenu.cc  
    src/stateestimation/main_stateestimation.cpp
    src/stateestimation/DroneKalmanFilter.cpp
    src/stateestimation/Predictor.cpp
  src/stateestimation/PTAMWrapper.cpp
  src/stateestimation/MapView.cpp
  src/stateestimation/EstimationNode.cpp
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/ATANCamera.cc
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/Bundle.cc
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/HomographyInit.cc
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/KeyFrame.cc
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/Map.cc
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/MapMaker.cc
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/MapPoint.cc
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/MiniPatch.cc
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/PatchFinder.cc
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/Relocaliser.cc
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/ShiTomasi.cc
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/SmallBlurryImage.cc
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/Tracker.cc
)
set(STATEESTIMATION_HEADER_FILES    
  src/stateestimation/GLWindow2.h 
  src/stateestimation/GLWindowMenu.h    
  src/stateestimation/MouseKeyHandler.h  
  src/HelperFunctions.h   
  src/stateestimation/DroneKalmanFilter.h        
  src/stateestimation/Predictor.h 
  src/stateestimation/PTAMWrapper.h
  src/stateestimation/MapView.h
  src/stateestimation/EstimationNode.h
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/ATANCamera.h
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/Bundle.h
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/customFixes.h
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/HomographyInit.h
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/KeyFrame.h
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/LevelHelpers.h
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/Map.h
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/MapMaker.h
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/MapPoint.h
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/MEstimator.h
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/MiniPatch.h
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/OpenGL.h
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/PatchFinder.h
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/Relocaliser.h
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/settingsCustom.h
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/ShiTomasi.h
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/SmallBlurryImage.h
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/SmallMatrixOpts.h
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/TrackerData.h
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/Tracker.h
  src/stateestimation/PTAM/VideoSource.h
)

# set required libs and headers
include_directories(
  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/thirdparty/src/thirdparty/TooN/include 
  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/thirdparty/src/thirdparty/libcvd/include 
  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/thirdparty/src/thirdparty/gvars3/include 
)  

link_directories(
  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/thirdparty/src/thirdparty/libcvd/lib 
  ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/thirdparty/src/thirdparty/gvars3/lib 
)
set(PTAM_LIBRARIES GL glut cvd GVars3 blas lapack)
add_definitions(-DKF_REPROJ)

# build!
add_executable(drone_stateestimation ${STATEESTIMATION_SOURCE_FILES} ${STATEESTIMATION_HEADER_FILES})
set_target_properties(drone_stateestimation PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-D_LINUX -D_REENTRANT -Wall  -O3 -march=nocona -msse3") 
target_link_libraries(drone_stateestimation ${PTAM_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(drone_stateestimation thirdparty ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencpp ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencfg)

# ------------------------- autopilot & KI -----------------------------------------
# set header ans source files
set(AUTOPILOT_SOURCE_FILES         
    src/autopilot/main_autopilot.cpp  
    src/autopilot/ControlNode.cpp
    src/autopilot/DroneController.cpp
    src/autopilot/KI/KILand.cpp
    src/autopilot/KI/KIAutoInit.cpp
    src/autopilot/KI/KIFlyTo.cpp
)
set(AUTOPILOT_HEADER_FILES        
    src/autopilot/ControlNode.h
    src/autopilot/DroneController.h
    src/autopilot/KI/KILand.h
    src/autopilot/KI/KIAutoInit.h
    src/autopilot/KI/KIFlyTo.h
    src/autopilot/KI/KIProcedure.h
)

# build!
add_executable(drone_autopilot ${AUTOPILOT_SOURCE_FILES} ${AUTOPILOT_HEADER_FILES})
target_link_libraries(drone_autopilot ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(drone_autopilot thirdparty ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencpp ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencfg)

# ---------------------------- GUI --------------------------------------------------
# set header ans source files
set(GUI_SOURCE_FILES         
    src/UINode/main_GUI.cpp  
    src/UINode/tum_ardrone_gui.cpp  
    src/UINode/RosThread.cpp  
    src/UINode/PingThread.cpp  
)

set(GUI_HEADER_FILES        
    src/UINode/tum_ardrone_gui.h 
    src/UINode/RosThread.h  
    src/UINode/PingThread.h  
)

# *.ui
set(GUI_UI_FILES        
    src/UINode/tum_ardrone_gui.ui 
)

# *.qrc
set(GUI_RESOURCE_FILES        
)

# do QT stuff
ADD_DEFINITIONS( -Wall )
find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)
include(${QT_USE_FILE})
QT4_ADD_RESOURCES(GUI_RESOURCE_FILES_CPP ${GUI_RESOURCE_FILES})
QT4_WRAP_UI(GUI_UI_FILES_HPP ${GUI_UI_FILES})
QT4_WRAP_CPP(GUI_HEADER_FILES_HPP ${GUI_HEADER_FILES})
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})

# build!
add_executable(drone_gui ${GUI_SOURCE_FILES} ${GUI_RESOURCE_FILES_CPP} ${GUI_UI_FILES_HPP} ${GUI_HEADER_FILES_HPP})
target_link_libraries(drone_gui ${QT_LIBRARIES} cvd ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(drone_gui thirdparty ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencpp ${PROJECT_NAME}_gencfg)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236197/ros-two-different-nodes-in-the-same-package/) by [Geaper](https://answers.ros.org/users/27087/geaper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-06-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-06**:
Please don't post *answers* unless you are actually *answering* your own question. For everything else, either *edit* your original question to update it, or comments (but only for short bits). I've merged your last post into your question, but please keep it in mind next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> type="drone_autopilot"

The `type` attribute is what ultimately determines which binary is run, not the `name`.

So I guess changing `drone_autopilot` to `drone_autopilot2` would do the trick, if I understand your question correctly.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Geaper](https://answers.ros.org/users/27087/geaper/) on 2016-06-06**:
Thank you for your help. Gives me: Error Cannot launch node of type tum_ardrone_droneautopilot2.

**Comment by [Geaper](https://answers.ros.org/users/27087/geaper/) on 2016-06-06**:
Basically I copy-paste the folders inside src ( Autopilot,StateEstimation and UINode ) and changed the code in each one to read /drone1/image_raw and /drone2/image_raw in ( Autopilot2,StateEstimation2 and UINode2 ).

**Comment by [Geaper](https://answers.ros.org/users/27087/geaper/) on 2016-06-06**:
The problem is that when I run roslaunch it only starts 2 instances of the nodes Autopilot,StateEstimation and UINode  and not Autopilot,StateEstimation and UINode  and  Autopilot2,StateEstimation2 and UINode2

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-06**:
The problem is that just copying files is not enough, they won't get build. You'll have to add them to your `CMakeLists.txt`, as @jarvisschultz already mentioned.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-06**:
But the bigger issue here is: why did you create exact copies of the source files in the first place? Was it to change their name? Because that is not necessary, you can just use the `name` attribute in the launch file, as you discovered.